# Does the htaccess rules add up or cancel each other?

Tags: .htaccess

Quick question: Is this

```
Options -ExecCGI -MultiViews -Includes -IncludesNOEXEC -Indexes -SymLinksifOwnerMatch FollowSymLinks
```

equivalent to this

```
Options None
Options FollowSymLinks
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`htaccess` files are linear .. Meaning the directive nearest the bottom of the page will override a directive above it if they are the same, IE:

```
AllowOverride All
```

Then

```
AllowOverride None
```

The `AllowOverRide None` would be the one the file "executes" since it is below `AllowOverride All` .. Conversely, an `.htaccess` file with the same directives but in a sub-directory will override the the .htaccess directives in the directory **above** if the directives exist in both `.htaccess` files.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is YES as per the manual: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#options